Return the most recent unit price of a matching item that is dated on or before a specified lookup date
In Google Sheets I have a list of orders recorded by order date, item, and price.
There is one order per row, but the same items are ordered on different dates and the prices vary between orders.
I'm trying to return the most recent order price for a lookup item restricted to only orders made on or before a specified date.
In the sample data below, my lookup values (batch date and item) are in the sheet "Batching log" while the lookup range is in "Orders".
Batching log (sheet 1)



batch date
item
unit price




1-feb-2024
sand
formula



Orders (sheet 2)



order date
Item
unit price




05-feb-2024
sand
$2.50


20-jan-2024
sand
$2.00


21-apr-2024
stone
$32.00


27-oct-2023
timber
$13.00


12-nov-2023
sand
$5.00


28-jan-2024
timber
$12.00


13-mar-2024
stone
$35.00



Based on the data above, the formula in 'Batching log'!C2 should return a unit price of $2.00
This is because, of the three separate orders whose item is "sand" (rows 2, 3,and 6), row 2's date 20-jan-2024 is the most recent without exceeding the lookup date.
There are some similar questions on the site but they're different enough that I can't quite work it out.

Nice one! I made edits to your post but  was really impressed by quality of your question, especially, including the  markdown tables. If you are not comfortable with any of the edits, feel free to make changes or even roll the entire edit back.

VLOOKUP
=VLOOKUP(A2, SORT(FILTER(Orders!A:C, Orders!B:B=B2)), 3, 1)

FILTER  SORT  VLOOKUP

FILTER Orders sheet for rows where item is "sand" and SORT by date.
Use VLOOKUP to match the date using is_sorted=1 which returns the closest date that is equal to or less, and return the value in column index 3.

INDEX and SORT
=INDEX(
   SORT(
     Orders!C2:C,   
     Orders!B2:B=B2,0, 
     Orders!A2:A<=A2,0, 
     Orders!A2:A,0), 1)

INDEX  SORT

The unit price column is sorted by the following columns:

A column of 1's and 0's from testing each row in Orders for Item="sand"
Another similar column from testing if order date<=batch date
The last column is simply the order date


INDEX returns the first row from the array of unit prices returned by SORT

SORTN
As pointed out by @the-god-of-biscuits, the combination of INDEX and SORT can be replaced by a single function, SORTN.
=SORTN(
   Orders!C2:C, 1, 0,   
   Orders!B2:B=B2,0, 
   Orders!A2:A<=A2,0, 
   Orders!A2:A,0)

SORTN

SORTN has the number of rows to return set to 1 and duplicate handling is set to 0 (no duplicates).
The rest of the formula mirrors the previous one except INDEX is no longer needed.

QUERY
=QUERY(
   Orders!A2:C, "SELECT C WHERE B = '"& B2 &"' 
   AND A <= date '"& TEXT(E2,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'
   ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 1") 

QUERY  TEXT

Queries the range Orders!A2:C where:

Order item=Batch item
order date<=Batch date


Sorts the results by order date descending.
Limits the results to 1 row, which is the most recent Batch price whose date and item match the conditions.


Also doable with SORTN: =sortn(Orders!C2:C,1,0,Orders!B2:B=B2,0,Orders!A2:A<=A2,0)

Not sure why you think SORTN isn't an array formula - it accepts scalar operators/functions within the sort_column arguments and iterates them over the associated range/array without needing an ARRAYFORMULA/INDEX wrapper in exactly the same manner as SORT & FILTER, and of course will return >1 result if the n argument >1...

No problem! - you weren't being a jerk. Good spot re. the missing date column in my answer - my answer worked on the example data but wouldn't have worked more generally.
